# How to add obfuscator-llvm to Rust compile tool-chains?

Tags: rust, llvm, crypto-obfuscator

I want to obfuscate my Rust code with ollvm, but I havn't find some describtion about how to add ollvm into compile chain. How could I do that?

Comment: Compared to .NET, Rust compiles to machine code, sooo, good luck disassembling that to something usable.

Comment: @vallentin there's decompilers and reverse-engineering frameworks out there, and people who are surprisingly good at using them and recovering something quite similar to the original (at least for C and C++, not sure if there are skilled Rust-reverse-engineers quite yet). That they exist is basically why projects like ollvm do as well.

Comment: I must admit, I've mainly decompiled Java years ago. Though I'd imagine recovering types and lifetimes into a state in which it can be compiled again without issues, would be extremely difficult in Rust.